# How to use threads?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-fragments

I'm trying to use threads because there is too much work on the UI Thread.
The app works but it's still slow.
Is there something wrong with the Fragment I'm trying to create?

Java Code For Fragment

```
import android.media.Image;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import org.w3c.dom.Text;
import android.view.View;


public class headercode extends Fragment implements Runnable {

    ImageView image;
    TextView text;
    View myView;
    Thread thread;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag, container, false);
        thread = new Thread();
        this.run();
        return myView;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        thread.start();
        image = (ImageView)myView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ahmed);
    }


}
```

Main Activity code OnCreate() method;

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.Button;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener   {




    Button button;
    headercode header;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);



        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();



        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        if (findViewById(R.id.fragment) != null){

            header = new headercode();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment,header).commit();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Your code is not multithreading, it is just creating an (empty) thread and running it.  It takes a lot more than simply saying `Thread t = new Thread(); t.start();` to move work into a new thread!

Comment: I think you what something like. thread = new Thread(this); thread.start();

Answer (score 0):

Because your thread is just empty, try this:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Your code here
    }
}).start();
```

Comment: The class implements Runnable, what do you mean the Thread is empty?

Comment: Oh, I mean he just created a thread and run it without any code inside, so nothing happen. My english is not so good and im so sorry about that

Comment: I know what you meant. Your English was fine. I was referring to the line that has `this.run();`

Answer (score 0):

> there is too much work on the UI Thread. The App works but its still slow.

Well, first, this is the only code in a Thread in your question.

```
@Override
public void run(){
    thread.start();
    image = (ImageView)myView.findViewById(R.id.image);
    image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ahmed);
}
```

But, you have to do `new Thread(this).start();` if you would like that code to run from a Thread. The other `Thread` is empty.

You should instead follow some of the documentation at [**Displaying Bitmaps Effieciently**](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html) if you are just concerned about images.

Alternatively, you can use an image loading library to do that work for you. (To prevent bias, I'll let the search for that be up to you).

> I'm trying to use threads

That's great and all, but I believe the recommended approach is a `Handler` or, if necessary, an `AsyncTask`.

Unfortunately, there isn't much else to go on based your code to accurately answer what is slow.